# How to reset Count down timer in JavaScript when refresh

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

I have a problem with countdown timer.
After refreshing page it`s start counting from now.

This is from index.html

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#countdown14').ClassyCountdown({
     theme: "black-black",
     labelsOptions: {
       style: 'font-size:0.5em; text-transform:uppercase;'
     },
     end: $.now() + 3387600
   });
 });
```

Full code you can see [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVEZoe)

Here is the  html for count down timer code

```
<div class="container clock">
  <div class="text1"> End in </div>

  <div id="countdown14" class="ClassyCountdownDemo">
  </div>
</div>
```

Suggestion and correction are welcome

Comment: What is the expected result? What is the problem?

Comment: what is the expected behavior ?

Comment: spb.ogneza.com , we have discount till 31 jan 2016y and this times should countdown to this date , but every time you open this page it is start 39 days and 5hours. does not metter if you open it today or tomorrow.

Comment: clarify your question and make precise what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a `Date` object with the date in the future when you want the countdown to end. Instead of setting `$.now() + x` you just get the time of the just created object:

```
var endDate = new Date(2016, 1, 31);

$('#countdown14').ClassyCountdown({
    theme: "black-black",
    labelsOptions: {
        style: 'font-size:0.5em; text-transform:uppercase;'
    },
    end: endDate.getTime()
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, tried to add new obj to script but can`t find the right place for it, if you can suggest what is I have to replace. or any other information.

Comment: You must do it exactly like I've did in the answer... copy paste?